# redirecting webpage when port forwarded server is offline

Tags: router, port-forwarding, webserver

I have a website and I point it to my routers IP address. I then have a server with a static IP and port forward ( port 80) all incoming website requests to my server.

My question is, when I turn my server off and then try to access my website, it redirects me to the login page of my router which makes sense but not secure. Is there anyway to change this or redirect it so it does't go to my routers login page?

Answer (score 0):

I highly suggest you change your router password to something long, 12-20 characters if possible.  It's not exactly easy for you to see if someone is trying to get into your router so the longer the pass the longer it'll take to bruteforce.  It's not the best solution but it is an okay one.  Some routers have a password of the day login too which depending on the model is extremely easy to get.  It's a different password than the router password and doesn't give access to the same stuff, just depends on the router you have of what is visible to the outside world.  You could always host 2 web servers, 1 specifically for preventing anyone outside from ever reaching your router on port 80 and a way of saying something like "our website is in maintenance" or something.  The second web server could be the one you're using now.  That solution isn't ideal if the reason it's offline is because the computer is turned off however.  Keep in mind if you do that sort of thing, your isp may not be able to reach your modem either (which may or may not actually be a big deal).